# django styling with multiple extended templates with allauth

Tags: django, django-templates, django-allauth

I'm customizing a handful of the allauth templates, so I've moved them to my `templates->account` directory, everything works fine there.

```
Project
|-- templates
    |-- base.html
    |-- account
        |-- base.html
        |-- email_confirm.html
        |-- verification_sent.html
```

The problem is I want to add some styling to each of them. It feels like `account/base.html` would be the place to add this styling, since it is only specific to the allauth templates, and they extend this template, but I can't figure out how to do that.  all I've come up with is..

**project/templates/base.html**

```
...
        <div class="main-container">

            {% block format_auth %}
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
...
```

**project/templates/account/base.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block special_format %}
    <div class="allauth-styling">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**project/templates/account/confirm_email.html**

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>{% trans "Verify Your E-mail Address" %}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

but this feels like a hack, as I don't think I should be needing to modify my top level `base.html` file.

Comment: Better not to have nested blocks, if you want to add styles give them their own block

Comment: but the allauth templates use `{% block content %}`, so I'd have to change all of those wouldn't I?